# Check the first character of all words in an array and return the one that starts with eg "a or etc" in the array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to find the first character in the array which is contained by a few words.

I got all the words but I don't know how to check the first character of all????!!!!!

```
def strange_words(words)
  newarray = []
  i = 0
  while i < words.length
    letters = words[i]
    if ???? #problem is here

    end 
    i += 1
  end
  return newarray   
end

puts strange_words(["eating", "period", "value", "earth"])
```

for example, the first character in value is "v" and I want that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Array#select](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-select) *Returns a new array containing all elements of ary for which the given block returns a true value.*

```
def strange_words(array, started_character)
  array.select{|m| m.start_with?(started_character)}
end
```

Output:

```
strange_words(["eating", "period", "value", "earth"], 'ea') 
#=> ["eating", "earth"]
```

Cheers

Comment: Useful , glad for the answer

Answer (score 1):

I have assumed that all words having the desired property are to be returned in an array rather than the first such word only. The question is not clear about that, as reflected in the differing answers.

```
def strange_words(words, begins_with)
  words.grep /\A#{begins_with}/
end

words = ["eating", "period", "value", "earth", "vortex", "evenly"]

strange_words(words, "v")
  #=> ["value", "vortex"]
strange_words(words, "ea")
  #=> ["eating", "earth"]
strange_words(words, "z")
  #=> []
```

See [Enumerable#grep](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep). The regular expressions reads, "match the beginning of the string (`\A`) followed by the string that is the value of `begins_with`".

If only the first match is to be returned one option would be to make `grep` a lazy enumerator in order to stop the search after the first match is found:

```
def strange_words(words, begins_with)
  words.lazy.grep(/\A#{begins_with}/).first
end
strange_words(words, "v")
  #=> "value"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array#find](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) does exactly this. It returns the first element which matches the condition in the block:

You can make a method like this:

```
def first_word_starting_with(array, characters)
  array.find { |el| el.start_with? characters }
end

arr = ["eating", "period", "value", "earth"]
first_word_starting_with(arr, "v")
# => "value"
```

Comment: Got it , so much helpful tnx